# Specify a week by using a date

Tags: dates

I wish to refer to a specific week which contains the date I mention. Example:

```
I suggest the week of November 9th for our meeting.
```

where I refer to the date range Monday 9.11. to Friday 13.11.

How do I correctly write this in English?

Comment: Just for extra clarity, you could add Monday to you sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use 'week commencing the 9th of November', or even use what you already have.  The sentence you use is common and understood in English.

Comment: Is it common/understandable to use **concluding** to mentioning the ending date? e.g. Week concluding 13th.